# Android: Foursquare MapView + TableView scroll effect. Thoughts?

Tags: android, dictionary, tableview, foursquare, parallax

I am a designer working with one of my developer. We want to implement the 'scroll' effect on Foursquare's previous version. However, after many stumbles and no no help from anyone we turn to Stackoverflow.

There seem to be some help for the iOS version, but what about the Android? Any help would do!

We have tried:
-tweeting about this
-checked Github, but no results

Comment: Here is the iOS one I found [iOS Map + List scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844277/scrollview-like-foursquare-with-maps-list)